# Getting set state of latitude and longitude in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, geolocation

I am creating an app that needs to get the latitude and longitude of the user.

I am using react-native-geolocation-services to get the information.

Here is my code.

```js
 componentDidMount() {
    hasLocationPermission().then(result => {
      this.setState({_isLocationEnabled: result});
    });
    if (hasLocationPermission) {
      Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        position => {
          this.setState({
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          });
          console.log(this.state.latitude);
          console.log(this.state.longitude);
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error.code, error.message);
        },
        {
          enableHighAccuracy: true,
          timeout: 15000,
          maximumAge: 10000,
        },
      );
    }
    const fetch = require('node-fetch');
    console.log(this.state.latitude);
    fetch(
      'https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?q=' +
        this.state.latitude +
        ',' +
        this.state.longitude,
      {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      },
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        console.log(responseJson);
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson,
        });
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

As you can see from my code if the device has location permissions then I get the geo location and the current position. After this I set the state of the latitude and longitude. When I print them do the console they are sent.

When I try to use them within my fetch url by adding this.state.latitude then are undefined. Why is this? what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is async so when you receive the position, the code that do the fetch has already been executed.

In order to fix this you need to do something like the following:

```
componentDidMount() {
hasLocationPermission().then(result => {
  this.setState({_isLocationEnabled: result});
});
if (hasLocationPermission) {
  Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    position => {
      this.setState({
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude,
      }, () => {
        const fetch = require('node-fetch');
        console.log(this.state.latitude);
        fetch(
          'https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?q=' +
            this.state.latitude +
            ',' +
            this.state.longitude,
          {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
              Accept: 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
          },
        )
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(responseJson => {
            console.log(responseJson);
            this.setState({
              isLoading: false,
              dataSource: responseJson,
            });
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      });
      console.log(this.state.latitude);
      console.log(this.state.longitude);
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error.code, error.message);
    },
    {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 15000,
      maximumAge: 10000,
    },
  );
}
```

Basically you need to execute the fetch after the `setState` has been completed so you can read the updated state.

Comment: I will try and give this a go

Comment: this fixed the problem, thank you for your help